# Testing command in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have written some functions in C and I want to compile them with a Makefile.

Before compiling I want to make a command to test them with another command and then compile them only if they passed the tests.

What I am thinking about :

```
tests :
   gcc tests.c
all : tests
   gcc *.c
```

I want to compile the tests.c and then if they are OK to compile all the functions.

How can I do this ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

General outline for building `realproduct` only after tests pass:

```
all: realproduct

realproduct: | run-tests

run-tests: tests
        ./$<
```

How does it work?

there's an implicit rules to compile `tests.c` into `tests` executable, it will run `cc tests.c -o tests` and you can modify it with `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, `LDLIBS` variables.

`$<` means first dependency, and `./` is a path to it, so it means run `tests` executable from local directory

`|` is placed before "order-only dependency", which means that `run-tests` must be "made" before `realproduct`, but `run-tests` is not part of "buildin" `realproduct`. Thus, `cc realproduct.c -o realproduct` will be invoked to build.

So, in summary, whenever `tests.c` is changed, first `tests` will be built, then `./tests` will be ran, then `realproduct` will be built:

```
$ make
cc     tests.c   -o tests
./tests
cc     realproduct.c   -o realproduct
```

Finally you can use https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html to make sure some commands are always ran, not only when dependencies have changed.